# Job failed using Gitlab

Tags: android, android-ndk, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have used the Gitlab for run the CI plan.

***Problem sequence:***

1. Run the CI plan, with below yaml script, now CI getting passed
2. Again run the CI plan, now CI getting failed with below error code

   ***warning: failed to remove MediaDrmCts/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/output.json: Invalid argument***

***Environment:***
Gitlab runner in Windows PC
Shell

***Yaml Code:***

```
assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo 'start building...'
    - cd MediaDrmCts
    - ./gradlew clean assemble
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - MediaDrmCts/app/build/outputs/

debugTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd MediaDrmCts
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug
```

***Error Log:***
[image: error log]

Please help us to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please guys, help me??

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the issues in GitLab with killing processes on Windows:

*tl;dr* the windows runner (current version is around ~13.6 with no fix yet) can't kill the full tree of processes started in the job properly, so processes holding file locks are left around for the next job/pipeline to fail on when it attempts to clean up

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3185
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3121

I've had similar issues in the past and a workaround is to clean up troublesome directories in the job that makes them, rather than letting the git clean command clean them up in the next job.

**One option:**

```
debugTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd MediaDrmCts
    - ./gradlew -Pci --console=plain :app:testDebug
  after_script:
    - if (Test-Path ./MediaDrmCts/app/build) { Remove-Item ./MediaDrmCts/app/build -Recurse -Force; }
...
```

**Another option**

If your builds aren't sensitive to how clean the repo folder is, then you can try turning off the `git clean -ffdx` step in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
...
variables:
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: none
...
```

which will tell the GitLab runner not to attempt cleaning up the repository of extra files before each run.

Keep in mind that this may have some unintended consequences, such as the wrong files being left over from previous runs on other branches, so be wary, and have good tests!